# How to run just one background process of a php file in cpanel cron jobs?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I need to run my php script in **background** using **cpanel cron job**, the script is an **infinity loop** that may be stoped sometimes, how to have **just one process** of the same file running in background? I mean is it possible to **check for background processes** and if the same file **was not running** the cron job run it, otherwise **don't do anything**.
I tried something like this for file `phpscript.php`:

```sh
ps -ef|grep phpscript.php |grep -v grep; if [ $? == "0" ]; then echo "Running"; else echo "Restart";php /path/to/restart/phpscript.php &; fi >/home/username/cronlogs.txt 2>&1;
```

But I got an empty log file each time, what is the correct way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forget the == there :

```
if [ $? = "0" ]
```

You should replace it by :

```
if [ $? == "0" ]
```

Furthermore, if you can install application on the server, maybe you should take a look at supervisord which permit you to : Run an application as a daemon and restart it if the application is not running.

Comment: thanks, that just was mistyped code here, I used `==` before

Comment: You are welcome,I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer.

Comment: it's not the correct solution, I said I tried == before and didn't work

Comment: Ok, 

Could you try the following : 

pgrep phpscript.php || php /path/to/restart/phpscript.php > /home/username/cronlogs.txt